# C++ Constructor with other class-data-type

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constructor

first of all, hi to everyone,

i'm new to this forum, so i hope, i haven't made any rookie-mistakes, if so - please correct me :). Second: English is not my native language, so i hope i can make my problem clear.

Regarding my problem:

I have to write a C++ program with 2 classes, class 1 Date with 3x unsigned int for day, month and year, and class 2 Time with 2x unsigned int for minute and hour,and 1x Date.

- each class has a default constructor which calls the overload constructor (we have to work with initialiser lists)
  My problem is, that i just cant figure out, how i can use a member of class Date in my Time class.

I know it's not exactly clear what my problem is, so here's a simplified version of my code:
main:

```
#include "Date.hpp"
#include "Time.hpp" //(+ iomanip / iostream)

int main(){
Date d1; //Calls Default Constructor of class Date, which initialises with (1,1,2000)
Time t1(d1,23,30); //should call ovrld-constr. of class Time and keep the date of d1
```

in my "Time.cpp" i tried smth like:

```
Time::Time(Date x, unsigned int y, unsigned int z)
  : d(Date::Date(x)), minute(y), hour(z) //try to call the def constr of class Date
{
return;
} 

Time::Time() : Time(Date::Date(), 00, 00) //should call the ovrld constr of class Time
{
return;
}
```

but of course it doesn't work...The Compiler always says:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x35c):undefined reference to `Time::Time()'
```

if it helps, here's a extract of my (completely working) "Date.cpp":

```
Date::Date(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int z)
 : day(x), month(y), year(z)
{
if(valiDate(day, month, year)==false){ //ValiDate is a function which checks the input                          
day=1;month=1;year=2000;} //default date, if Date is not Valid
return;
} 

Date::Date() : Date(1,1,2000)
{
return;
}
```

I hope this was enough to make my problem clear, if not, i can always show you the complete source code. Important note: I'm not (!) allowed to edit the main.cpp.
Also, if someone could explain my mistake rather than just posting a complete solution, it would be greatly appreciated, because i think that a solution which I -in a worst case- don't even understand doesn't help me much with my study.

Thanks in advance for the help,

best regards.

edit:

I'm sorry i forgot the two class.hpp.

1)The working Date.hpp (extract)

```
class Date
{

public:
  Date();
  Date(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int);


private:

  unsigned int day, month, year; 
  bool valiDate(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int);
};
```

2)my (not working) Time.hpp.

```
class Time
{

  public:

  Time();
  Time(Date, unsigned int, unsigned int);

  private:

  unsigned int minute, hour;
  Date d;

};
```

Comment: Have you added Time.cpp to your project?

Comment: Provide a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org) instead of an unstructured mess of code snippets!

Comment: Show us your Time.hpp

Comment: What was the compilation command that resulted in *main.cpp:(.text+0x35c):undefined reference to `Time::Time()'*?

Comment: well normaly i compile with: g++ main.cpp date.cpp time.cpp -std=c++11. Or with a makefile.

Comment: well and in this case?

Comment: g++ main.cpp date.cpp time.cpp -std=c++11

Comment: As it currently stands, you have **a lot** of compilation errors, none of which is an *undefined reference to `Time::Time()'*. As mentioned earlier, provide a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org) rather than an unstructured mess of code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your project and found dozens of compilation and linking errors, but no such error as you've specified.  Here's what I did find:

`class Time` contains a data member of type Date by value, so you need to `#include Date.hpp` in Time.hpp.  If you haven't already done so, you need to add [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to your headers.

You don't need to explicitly specify the Date constructor in the member initializer of Time, since it's being called anyway:

```
Time::Time(Date x, unsigned int y, unsigned int z)
  : d(Date::Date(x)), minute(y), hour(z) //try to call the def constr of class Date
{
    return;
}
```

can just be:

```
Time::Time(Date x, unsigned int y, unsigned int z)
    : d(x), minute(y), hour(z)
{

}
```

Note that you don't need to write `return` statements in constructors either.
Also note that `: d(x)` invokes Date's copy constructor, not the default constructor.  You haven't defined a copy constructor, and so one is being implicitly created for you to do a shallow copy.

You're also calling one constructor from another:

```
Time::Time() : Time(Date::Date(), 00, 00)
Date::Date() : Date(1,1,2000)
```

Delegating constructors is supported in C++11 but not yet supported by all compilers, but you can just initialize the members yourself:

```
Time::Time() : minute(0),hour(0)
Date::Date() : day(1),month(1),year(2000)
```

Comment: yup i know that "constructor calls constructor" is c++11, but we have to use it, where ever possible ;) The other tips like: include Date.hpp in Time.hpp and that i dont need to specifically call Date::Date() were more than helpful, because i only needed to ad "{ }" to "Time::Time() : Time(Date::Date(), 00, 00)", so thank you very much :) Can i somehow "Upvote" your answer?